# unauthorized access exception c#

Tags: c#, access-denied, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have this method

```
 public void Copy(string sourcePath, string destPath)
 {
     string[] files= Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
     for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
     {
         try
         {
             File.Copy(files[i], destPath);
         }
         catch
         {
             try
             {
                 File.Replace(files[i], destPath, null);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

when I run it I get unauthorized access exception , Access denied ! 
any help in this !

Comment: Run your program as an administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unauthorized Access Exception in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987232/unauthorized-access-exception-in-windows-7)

Comment: maybe you don't have write-access to the destination Path, as the error message says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception is covered in the [documentation for File.Copy:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

```
The caller does not have the required permission.
-or-
destFileName is read-only.
```

Check the attributes of the file after the first copy. Are the permissions what you expect? Do you need your program to run elevated (as administrator)?

Answer (score 1):

below reasons can possible :

The sourceFileName or destinationFileName parameter specifies a file that is read-only.

-or-
This operation is not supported on the current platform.

-or-
Source or destination parameters specify a directory instead of a file.

-or-
The caller does not have the required permission.

Read link :[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9etk7xw2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9etk7xw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When the problem occurs on a Windows machine, make sure you have disabled "controlled folder access" in the App Windows-Safety or allow folder access to your program. (must have administrator privileges)